# Menu items don't appear in nibless StatusMenu app?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I've been working on an application port that must show a status menu and some dynamic items within.  It's behaviour is similar to the apple WIFI menu which has an icon, some fixed items and some dynamic items in the center (the available WIFI networks).

For various reasons I decided to go nibless.  I've managed to get the menu icon to appear, but I can't seem to get the items to show in the menu when I click the icon.

This is what I have so far:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

// Strange, if these are not properties and not declared strong, 
// the menu flashes momentarily and disappears.  Could the dynamic menu items be related to object lifetime?
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSStatusItem *statusItem;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"LoginClicked");
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSLog(@"AppDidFinishLaunching!");
    self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [self.statusItem setMenu:self.statusMenu];

    NSImage *statusImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/applogo.png"];
     //menuImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"applogo" ofType:@"png"]];
    [self.statusItem setImage:statusImage];
    [self.statusItem setAlternateImage:statusImage];
    //[self.statusItem setTitle:@"MyApp"];
    [self.statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

    // Add login
    NSMenuItem *login = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" action:loginClicked keyEquivalent:@""];
    [self.statusMenu addItem:login];

    NSMenuItem *quit = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
    [self.statusMenu addItem:quit];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}
```

main.m

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool { // Do I need this or is it on by default?
      // make sure the application singleton has been instantiated
      NSApplication * application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];

      // instantiate our application delegate
      AppDelegate * applicationDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];

      // assign our delegate to the NSApplication
      [application setDelegate:applicationDelegate];

      // call the run method of our application
      [application run];
    }

    // execution never gets here...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much mucking around, I tried something that now seems obvious.

I don't know why, but in examples of StatusBar Apps that use nib, IBMenu is not alloc'ed and inited.  It appears to be done automatically somehow.

Adding the following seemed to fix it.

```
self.statusMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
```

Also, noting my comment on lifetime.  If I don't use properties, I have to set retain on statusItem when creating it.  Then it doesn't get destroyed.  I'm still learning about how objective-C managages object lifetime and still a bit confused about ARC here.  But it least it now seems to show my menu items.